# Is there a difference between an Int and a Maybe Int in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, int

Is there a difference between an `Int` and a `Maybe Int` in Haskell? And if there is, how do I convert a `Maybe Int` to an `Int`?

Comment: You'd benefit from reading a good haskell book like [this one](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [this one](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/). And please be a good citizen by marking answers correct.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are of different types: there is `Maybe Int` could be `Nothing` or `Just Int`, where `Int` is always `Int`.

Maybe is defined in `Data.Maybe` as

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
     deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

and should be used if a function may not return a valid value. Have a look at functions `isJust`, `isNothing`, and `fromJust` (use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), the Haskell API search engine).

Inside your function you can e.g.

```
case maybeValue of
  Just x     -> ... -- use x as value
  Nothing    -> ... -- erroneous case
```

Alternatively, use `fromMaybe` (also from `Data.Maybe`) which takes a default value and a `Maybe`
and returns the default value if the `Maybe` is a `Nothing`, or the actual value otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The `Maybe` data type represents a value that can be null, and is usually used as the return value from a function that can either succeed with just a value, or fail with no value.  It has two constructors: `Nothing` and `Just a`, where `a` is whatever value you're returning.  You can use it like this:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:xs) = Just x
```

You can extract the value using pattern matching, or using a handful of functions from `Data.Maybe`.  I usually prefer the former, so something like:

```
main = do
    let xs :: [Int]
        xs = someComputation 1 2 3
        xHead = safeHead xs
    case xHead of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "someComputation returned an empty list!"
        Just h  -> putStrLn $ "The first value is " ++ show h
        -- Here `h` in an `Int`, `xHead` is a `Maybe Int`
```

Comment: `fromJust`: ["The fromJust function extracts the element out of a Just and throws an error if its argument is Nothing."](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html)  It is better to avoid these error-prone functions, but they can be convenient shortcuts in some cases

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm fully aware of this function, but as you quoted it can throw an error, which I don't like.  Pattern matching forces you to consider both cases, which I consider to be much less bug prone.  It also doesn't require an extra import.  All in all, I see it as a better, more readable solution except in particular cases.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't implying you weren't aware.  But I understand your concern.  My intention was just to give an example of one of the "functions from Data.Maybe" that you referred to.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand about the above code is line 4?

Comment: @Eddie do you mean the `case xHead of` line?

Comment: @bheklilr the one above?

Comment: @Eddie It's part of the `let` clause.  It's storing the return value of `safeHead xs` in the name `xHead`.  In this case, `xHead` would have the type `Maybe Int`, since `xs` has the type `[Int]`.